# magento 2.3 after enabling system logs unable to run any command

Tags: log, magento2.3.1, debug

I have enabled system logs in magento 2.3.1 using command  bin/magento setup:config:set --enable-debug-logging=true
 But, after enabling it, I am unable to run any command in terminal and getting message -  Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html..

I want to disable the system logs, no command is working in terminal. 
Please provide a solution to disable it either through admin or database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check in your app/etc/env.php file, there should be something like:

```
    'dev' => [
        'debug' => [
            'debug_logging' => 1
        ]
    ]
```

Try removing it and check again if you can run commands

Comment: I have removed it but still unable to run any command.

Comment: And what is your php version? Have you checked the cli version too?

Comment: The default php version on server is 7.0 and the site I am working on is setup on Php 7.1 and it's cli version in also 7.1. 
But after enabling debug log it is showing issue of default PHP version on cli and not able to run any command.

Comment: I'm trying in a php 7.2 server without any issues, can you easily change the php to 7.2 to test?